# Index objects in pandas--why pd.columns returns index rather than list

Tags: python, pandas

Coming from R background, I find the (very high) use of `Index` objects in pandas a little disconcerting. For example, if `train` is a pandas DataFrame, is there some special reason why `train.columns` should return an `Index` rather than a list? What purpose would additionally be served if it is an `Index` object? As per the definition of `pandas.Index`, it is the  basic object storing axis labels for all pandas objects. While `train.index.values` does return the row labels (axis=0), how can I get column labels or columns names from `pandas.index`? In this question unlike in an earlier question, I have a specific example in mind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the point of indexing in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238066/what-is-the-point-of-indexing-in-pandas)

Comment: The link above has some good info about why all elements of the index being hashable matters.

Comment: Thanks. It does. I am going through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [`pandas.Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html)

> Immutable ndarray implementing an ordered, sliceable set. The basic object storing axis labels for all pandas objects

Having a regular list as an index for a DataFrame could cause issues with unorderable or unhashable objects, evidently - since it is backed by a hash table, the same principles apply as to why [lists can't be dictionary keys](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys) in regular Python.

At the same time, the Index object being explicit permits us to use different types as an Index, as compared to the implicit integer index that NumPy has for instance, and perform fast lookups.

If you want to retrieve a list of column names, the Index object has a `tolist` method.

```
>>> df.columns.tolist()
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Will be grateful if you can please expand upon the statement ' Having a regular list as an index for a DataFrame could cause issues with unorderable or unhashable objects, evidently. '. (Maybe  there is an example.)   Thanks.

Comment: @user3282777 An index is like a mapping to the DataFrame columns, sort of like a Python dict.  So the same principles apply as for why you can't have mutable types as dict keys in regular Python, which the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys) has a useful bit on.

Answer (score 5):

A `pd.Index` is an array-like container of the column names, so in some sense it doesn't make sense to ask how to get the labels from the index, because the index *is* the labels.

That said, you can always get the underlying numpy array with `df.columns.values`, or convert to a python list with `tolist()` as @Mitch showed.

In terms of why an index is used over a bare array - an `Index` provides extra functionality/performance used throughout pandas - the core of which is hash table based indexing.

By example, consider the following frame / columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10),
                  columns=list('abcdefghkm'))

cols = df.columns

cols
Out[16]: Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'k', 'm'], dtype='object')
```

Now say you want to select column `'h'` out of the frame.  With a list or array version of the columns, you would have loop over the columns to find the position of `'h'`, which is `O(n)` in the number of columns - something like this:

```
for i, col in enumerate(cols):
    if col == 'h':   
        found_loc = i
        break

found_loc
Out[18]: 7

df.values[:, found_loc]
Out[19]: 
array([-0.62916208,  2.04403495,  0.29498066,  1.07939374, -1.49619915,
       -0.54592646, -1.04382192, -0.45934113, -1.02935858,  1.62439231])

df['h']
Out[20]: 
0   -0.629162
1    2.044035
2    0.294981
3    1.079394
4   -1.496199
5   -0.545926
6   -1.043822
7   -0.459341
8   -1.029359
9    1.624392
Name: h, dtype: float64
```

With the `Index`, pandas constructs a hash table of the column values, so finding the location of 'h' is an amortized `O(1)` operation, generally significantly faster, especially if the number of columns is significant.

```
df.columns.get_loc('h')
Out[21]: 7
```

This example was only selecting a single column, but as @ayhan notes in the comment, this same hash table structure also speeds up many other operations like merging, alignment, filtering, and grouping.

Comment: It all comes down to finding the location of 'h' but it might be worth mentioning that this speeds up many other operations like grouping, subsetting, merging etc.

Comment: An Excellent and complete answer.