# using .columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Hi, I am using `.columns` attribute in pandas and I am getting `INDEX` at the beginning, can someone please let me know that why `INDEX` is mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: Because `.columns` returns a `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index` object, which happens to have `Index` in its string representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered before [Index objects in pandas--why pd.columns returns index rather than list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46221397/8840245), official documentation  [.index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html).

> Immutable ndarray implementing an ordered, sliceable set. The basic object storing axis labels for all pandas objects

If you are just expecting values then you've to go a little bit more. As `.columns` returns an Index , `.columns.values` returns an array and a helper function `.tolist` returns a list of column names.

```py
car_sales.columns.values.tolist()
```

You can use this `car_sales.columns.tolist()` too but won't perform good in large dataframes.