# Select rows of pandas dataframe from list, in order of list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*The question was originally asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe) as a comment but could not get a proper answer as the question was marked as a duplicate.*

For a given `pandas.DataFrame`, let us say

```
df = DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3, 5]})
df

     A   B
0    5   1
1    6   2
2    3   3
3    4   5
```

How can we select rows from a list, based on values in a column (`'A'` for instance)

For instance

```
# from
list_of_values = [3,4,6]

# we would like, as a result
#      A   B
# 2    3   3
# 3    4   5
# 1    6   2
```

Using `isin` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe) is not satisfactory as it does not keep order from the input list of `'A'` values.

How can the abovementioned goal be achieved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to overcome this is to make the `'A'` column an `index` and use `loc` on the newly generated `pandas.DataFrame`. Eventually, the subsampled dataframe's index can be reset.

Here is how:

```
ret = df.set_index('A').loc[list_of_values].reset_index(inplace=False)

# ret is
#      A   B
# 0    3   3
# 1    4   5
# 2    6   2
```

Note that the drawback of this method is that the original indexing has been lost in the process.

More on `pandas` indexing: [What is the point of indexing in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238066/what-is-the-point-of-indexing-in-pandas)

Comment: One question - all values of `list_of_values` are in column? Is possible `list_of_values = [3,4,6,7,7,4]` ?

Comment: in practice no but its true that this solution has the inconvenience of not handling out of column values

Comment: So the best is the most general solution with not remove original indices, working with duplicates values?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with helper `DataFrame` created by list and with column name of matched column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3,5]})

list_of_values = [3,6,4]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':list_of_values}).merge(df)
print (df1)
   A  B
0  3  3
1  6  2
2  4  5
```

For more general solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,5,3,4,4,6,5], 'B':range(8)})
print (df)
   A  B
0  5  0
1  6  1
2  5  2
3  3  3
4  4  4
5  4  5
6  6  6
7  5  7

list_of_values = [6,4,3,7,7,4]
```

---

```
#create df from list 
list_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list_of_values})
print (list_df)
   A
0  6
1  4
2  3
3  7
4  7
5  4

#column for original index values
df1 = df.reset_index()
#helper column for count duplicates values
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('A').cumcount()
list_df['g'] = list_df.groupby('A').cumcount()

#merge together, create index from column and remove g column
df = list_df.merge(df1).set_index('index').rename_axis(None).drop('g', axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B
1  6  1
4  4  4
3  3  3
5  4  5
```

Comment: Original index is lost in the process.

Comment: @Zero - Then is necessary `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':list_of_values}).merge(df.reset_index()).set_index('index').rename_axis(None)`

Comment: Actually, I found out this approach does not work in the case `list_of_values` contains repeated values: the order is not guaranteed to be kept. Im sorry I had to unvote as answer

Comment: @syltruong - I try create the more general solution for duplicates values `(4)` and also not matched values `(7)`.

Answer (score 1):

**1]** Generic approach for `list_of_values`.

```
In [936]: dff = df[df.A.isin(list_of_values)]

In [937]: dff.reindex(dff.A.map({x: i for i, x in enumerate(list_of_values)}).sort_values().index)
Out[937]:
   A  B
2  3  3
3  4  5
1  6  2
```

**2]** If `list_of_values` is sorted. You can use

```
In [926]: df[df.A.isin(list_of_values)].sort_values(by='A')
Out[926]:
   A  B
2  3  3
3  4  5
1  6  2
```