# How to maintain original dataframe index and keep order of input list when using isin()?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have the following dataframe:
`g= pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,42,5,7],'B':[5,6,7,3,2]})`

```
    A  B
0   1  5
1   2  6
2  42  7
3   5  3
4   7  2
```

am using the following list to filter the dataframe:

```
list_values = [5,7,1]
```

and get the following output using:

```
indexes = g[g['A'].isin(list_values)].index.values
```

output

```
array([0, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

How do I change the code so that indexes is the following?

```
array([3, 4, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Essentially, I am looking for a way to filter a DF with a list and return the original index values in the order of the filter list.

Thanks!

I looked at this but did not find what I was looking for: 
[Select rows of pandas dataframe from list, in order of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51944021/select-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-from-list-in-order-of-list/51944022#51944022)

Comment: @ALollz - I suppose that would be okay. The important thing is keeping the not loosing the original index values and returning a list in the order that is in the same order as list_values.

Comment: `np.array([g.loc[g.A==i].index[0] for i in list_values])` works only if the values in 'A' are unique and all elements from list exist in 'A'

Comment: @Asettisriharsha - That worked beautifully, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ordered `CategoricalDtype` to enforce a custom sorting order. After sorting you return all indices for 5, then 7, then 1.

```
import pandas as pd

my_cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=list_values, ordered=True)
#CategoricalDtype(categories=[5, 7, 1], ordered=True)

g.loc[g['A'].isin(list_values), 'A'].astype(my_cat).sort_values().index
#Int64Index([3, 4, 0], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: I tried this but got `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'CategoricalDtype'`  Which version are you using?

Comment: @DavidCollins 0.25.0. I'm pretty sure it's existed since a rather old version like `0.21.0`.

Comment: great, thanks!  I was using 0.20.3.  Never saw a reason to update.  Now I do, and did: 1.0.1