# Select rows of pandas dataframe in order of a given list with repetitions and keep the original index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51944021/select-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-from-list-in-order-of-list) and in the documentation, I still cannot find a way to select rows from a DataFrame according to *all* these criteria:

- Return rows in an order given from a list of values from a given column
- Return repeated rows (associated with repeated values in the list)
- Preserve the original indices
- Ignore values of the list not present in the DataFrame

As an example, let

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 6, 3, 4], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 5]})
df

     A   B
0    5   1
1    6   2
2    3   3
3    4   5
```

and let

```
list_of_values = [3, 4, 6, 4, 3, 8]
```

Then I would like to get the following DataFrame:

```
     A   B
2    3   3
3    4   5
1    6   2
3    4   5
2    3   3
```

How can I accomplish that? [Zero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51944169/6002956) looks promising as it is the only one I found which preserves the original index, but it does not work with repetitions. Any ideas about how to modify/generalize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to preserve the `index` by assigning it as a column first so we can `set_index` after the mering:

```
list_of_values = [3, 4, 6, 4, 3, 8]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': list_of_values, 'order': range(len(list_of_values))})

dfn = (
    df.assign(idx=df.index)
    .merge(df2, on='A')
    .sort_values('order')
    .set_index('idx')
    .drop('order', axis=1)
)
```

---

```
     A  B
idx      
2    3  3
3    4  5
1    6  2
3    4  5
2    3  3
```

If you want to get rid of the index name (`idx`), use `rename_axis`:

```
dfn = dfn.rename_axis(None)

   A  B
2  3  3
3  4  5
1  6  2
3  4  5
2  3  3
```

Comment: Thank you, this works indeed. As for renaming the index, I suppose that also `dfn.index = dfn.index.rename("")` would work, but it is surely more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do that using `merge`:

```
list_df = pd.DataFrame({"A": list_of_values, "order": range(len(list_of_values))})

pd.merge(list_df, df, on="A").sort_values("order").drop("order", axis=1)
```

The output is:

```
   A  B
0  3  3
2  4  5
4  6  2
3  4  5
1  3  3
```

Comment: I had an indention issue with the columns, but looking at A and B - seems to be identical to what you're looking for.

Comment: The problem is not in the columns, it is in the index.