# Accessing a Pandas index like a regular column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a named index. I want to pass it off to a piece off code that takes a DataFrame, a column name, and some other stuff, and does a bunch of work involving that column. Only in this case the column I want to highlight is the index, but giving the index's label to this piece of code doesn't work because you can't extract an index like you can a regular column. For example, I can construct a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'name':map(chr, range(97, 102)), 'id':range(10000,10005), 'value':np.random.randn(5)})
df.set_index('name', inplace=True)
```

Here's the result:

```
         id     value
name                 
a     10000  0.659710
b     10001  1.001821
c     10002 -0.197576
d     10003 -0.569181
e     10004 -0.882097
```

Now how am I allowed to go about accessing the `name` column?

```
print(df.index)  # No problem
print(df['name'])  # KeyError: u'name'
```

I know there are workaround like duplicating the column or changing the index to something else. But is there something cleaner, like some form of column access that treats the index the same way as everything else?

Comment: If you want this feature in pandas, please consider upvoting () this GitHub issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8162

Answer (score 33):

Index has a special meaning in Pandas. It's used to optimise specific operations and can be used in various methods such as merging / joining data. Therefore, make a choice:

- If it's "just another column", use `reset_index` and treat it as another column.
- If it's genuinely used for indexing, keep it as an index and use `df.index`.

We can't make this choice for you. It should be dependent on the structure of your underlying data and on how you intend to analyse your data.

For more information on use of a dataframe index, see:

- [What is the performance impact of non-unique indexes in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626058/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-non-unique-indexes-in-pandas)
- [What is the point of indexing in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238066/what-is-the-point-of-indexing-in-pandas)

Comment: Say I have a library function that takes a DataFrame and creates a scatter plot based on it. It labels points in the plot based on the column of your choice, currently specified as a string. Now a use case has come up where it would be useful for the labels to be based on the index of a certain DataFrame. The index of this DataFrame is undoubtedly _special_, as you say. It's just in the context of this one function where it would be convenient to treat the index like a regular column, and I'm wondering if it can be done transparently.

Comment: @kuzzooroo, I suggest you ask [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a [mcve] of the problem you are facing. The example you gave in your question, for example, doesn't *show* any problem with using `df.index`. The methods available to `pd.Index` objects are different to those available to `pd.Series` objects so we need to *see* your code to determine the issue.

Comment: One wonders what the point of giving the index a name is, if it can't be used as such like other column names ...

Comment: @guibar, you can with [pd.DataFrame.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

Comment: This is not really a solution and your answer is out of scope.

So what you're implying is that "no it's not possible because Pandas did not build an interface to interact the index like a column". If yes, then let this be the answer. Now a natural followup question is why not? We've seen other software being able to do this like SQL .

Comment: this is not an answer to the OP's question. it's a justification of why the problem exists in the first place... which is as a pandas user of more than a decade now, still confuses me why the API works this way.

Comment: @grisaitis, You have a couple of options: provide a better answer, or propose a Pandas code update to development team.

Comment: @jpp thanks. i've upvoted answers and github issues that i believe do that.

Answer (score 19):

You could also use `df.index.get_level_values` if you need to access a (index) column by name. It also works with hierarchical indices (`MultiIndex`).

```
>>> df.index.get_level_values('name')
Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], dtype='object', name='name')
```

Comment: Does this provide a form of access that is agnostic between the index and other named columns, or are you simply providing a different way to access an index that involves the index's name?

Comment: It's the latter -- it works only for the index columns.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using `reset_index`, you could just copy the index to a normal column, do some work and then drop the column, for example:

```
df['tmp'] = df.index
# do stuff based on df['tmp']
del df['tmp']
```

Comment: I like this solution too, in the end column and index serve different purposes, just keep both if needed.

Comment: If you keep both, they are not guaranteed to be synchronized