# Calculation of stock values with yfinance and python

Tags: python-3.x, yfinance

I would like to make some calculations on stock prices in Python 3 and I have installed the module yfinance.

I try to get an individual value like this:

```
import yfinance as yf

#define the ticker symbol
tickerSymbol = 'MSFT'

#get data on this ticker
tickerData = yf.Ticker(tickerSymbol)

#get the historical prices for this ticker
tickerDf = tickerData.history(period='1d', start='2015-1-1', end='2020-12-30')
row_date = tickerDf[tickerDf['Date']=='2020-12-30']
value = row_date.Open.item()

#see your data
print (value)
```

But when I run this, it says:

```
KeyError: 'Date'
```

Which is strange because when I do this, it works well and I have the column Date:

```
import yfinance as yf

#define the ticker symbol
tickerSymbol = 'MSFT'

#get data on this ticker
tickerData = yf.Ticker(tickerSymbol)

#get the historical prices for this ticker
tickerDf = tickerData.history(period='1d', start='2015-1-1', end='2020-12-30')
#row_date = tickerDf[tickerDf['Date']=='2020-12-30']
#value = row_date.Open.item()

#see your data
print (tickerDf)
```

I get the following result:

```
G:\python> python test.py
              Open        High         Low       Close    Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits
Date
2014-12-31   41.512481   42.143207   41.263744   41.263744  21552500        0.0             0
2015-01-02   41.450302   42.125444   41.343701   41.539135  27913900        0.0             0
2015-01-05   41.192689   41.512495   41.086088   41.157158  39673900        0.0             0
2015-01-06   41.201567   41.530255   40.455355   40.553074  36447900        0.0             0
2015-01-07   40.846223   41.272629   40.410934   41.068310  29114100        0.0             0
...                ...         ...         ...         ...       ...        ...           ...
2020-12-22  222.690002  225.630005  221.850006  223.940002  22612200        0.0             0
2020-12-23  223.110001  223.559998  220.800003  221.020004  18699600        0.0             0
2020-12-24  221.419998  223.610001  221.199997  222.750000  10550600        0.0             0
2020-12-28  224.449997  226.029999  223.020004  224.960007  17933500        0.0             0
2020-12-29  226.309998  227.179993  223.580002  224.149994  17403200        0.0             0

[1510 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hood, yfinance uses a Pandas data frame to create a Ticker. In this dataframe, `Date` isn't an ordinary column, but is instead a name given to the index (see line 240 in [base.py of yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/master/yfinance/base.py)). The index column behaves differently than other columns and actually can't be referenced by name. You can access it using `TickerDf.index=='2020-12-30'` or by turning it into a regular column using `reset_index` as explained in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139506/accessing-a-pandas-index-like-a-regular-column). Searching [through an index is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238066/what-is-the-point-of-indexing-in-pandas) than searching a regular column, so if you are looking through a lot of data, it will be to your advantage to leave it as an index.