# Incorrect df. iloc[:, 0]

Tags: python, pandas

My df has below columns

```
ID  Number  Name
11  ccc-456  dfg
45  ggt-56   ggg
33  67889    ttt
```

When I created a new dataframe (need it for merging with another dataframe)

```
df2 = df[['ID', 'Number']]
```

I got an error message stating ID is not in the index. But when I print(df), I do see the ID column.

When I ran the index
`df3 = df.iloc[:, 0]` I see first two columns ID and Number in the results

```
ID
24        32666
188       33432
401       34341
448       34490
510       34713
          ...  
14062    108789
14204    110710
14651    116332
14678    116733
14726    117600

Name: NUMBER, Length: 28149, dtype: int64
```

Why can i access the ID column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing a Pandas index like a regular column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139506/accessing-a-pandas-index-like-a-regular-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your issue:

Based on the information provided, your "ID" column is set to your dataframe index.

If you run this test code, you will get the same error that you described.

```
test_dict = {
    'ID': [11,45,33],
    'Number': ['ccc-456','ggt-56','67889'],
    'Name': ['dfg','ggg','ttt']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(test_dict).set_index('ID')
df2 = df[['ID', 'Number']]
```

### Solution

The easiest solution would be to do `df.reset_index(inplace = True)` before you create df2. This will give you the "ID" as a column so you can reference it as desired with `df2 = df[['ID', 'Number']]`

Comment: Thanks, @brian. I am getting 'Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series to create a DataFrame'

Comment: @Ziggy Are you using it on a separate lines? Is the `df` actually a dataframe? Based on that error you're trying to perform the operation on a series.
`df.reset_index(inplace = True)`
`df2 = df[['ID', 'Number']]`. You could also try not using inplace so just `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: @Ziggy Why are you trying to use it on a Series? Brian clearly wrote **`df`**

Comment: Apologies. And thank you so so much. @wjandrea and brain. It worked. df = df.reset_index()