# How can pandas index have duplicate values if they are hash table keys?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, hashtable

- I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238066/what-is-the-point-of-indexing-in-pandas) that pandas indexes are backed by a hash table
- I also know that hash tables cannot have duplicate keys

So why does the following code work:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','a','b'],'b':[1,2,3]}).set_index('a').loc['a',:]

output:
    b
a   
a   1
a   2
```

Comment: I'm guessing whatever is backing it won't have duplicates (or nulls), even though the indexes can be duplicates

Comment: As noted in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html), an index can be created from any array-like and it has methods to check for duplicates etc. So the direct answer to your question is that index values aren't hash table keys.